# How to edit labels on the line graph in R?

Tags: r

This is the graph [Covid according to dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gS14.png) is produced by this code:

```
ggplot(data = progressOfC, aes(x = day_count, y = total_cases, group = location)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = location, linetype = "solid")) + xlab("Day Count since 100th case") + 
  ylab("Cumulative cases(log-scale)") + geom_dl(aes(label = location), method = list("last.points", cex = 0.5))
```

But the names is coming in half, any ideas how can I get my names full?

Answer (score 0):

Try and add `geom_dl`. For that you also need the package `directlabels`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
ggplot(data = progressOfC, aes(x = day_count, y = total_cases, group = location, labels = rownames(location))) + 
          geom_line(aes(color = location, linetype = "solid"))+
          geom_dl(aes(label = location), method = list("last.points"), cex = 0.8)
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I have added the package directlabels and also added a code given by you but error is could not find geom_dl

Comment: Did you load the package? With `library(directlabels)`?

Comment: Yes I did load the package

Comment: If you first installed the package. `install.packages("directlabels")` and then load the package it should work. Otherwise it was not correctly installed or loaded.

Comment: @Elias are you sure there need to be two parentheses after `"last.points"`

Comment: Yes @Elias It did worked but the names are not loading full which means they are loading half and cutting the half name which go outside of graph  https://imgur.com/a/DFs7Eja

Comment: Yes @Elias It did worked but the names are not loading full which means they are loading half and cutting the half name which go outside of graph imgur.com/a/DFs7Eja

Comment: @V.Patel if you provide sample data we can help more. Otherwise you have to try yourself. You can use `dput()` to get sample data.

Comment: `method = list("smart.grid", cex = 0.8)`. You can try this.

Comment: Here we go I have the dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RwRkguE2I1jaUO9k2ePTZ6_1DKkAaC_E/view?usp=sharing